# What is wrong with this curve in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

So, consider the following curve:

$$\alpha(t) = \left( \sin(t), \sin(t^2)/2, ~\ldots~,~ \sin(t^n)/n~,~ \ldots\right).$$

This is certainly a curve in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, since the corresponding series is bounded above by $\sum 1/n^2$, **no matter what $t$ is**. So we have $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow l^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Also, each entry is certainly a smooth function. Now, I know that whenever we have a smooth curve $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow H$, where $H$ is any Banach space (in particular $l^2$), it has a derivative $\alpha' : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow H$.

However, differentiating entrywise the curve $\alpha$, one gets

$$\alpha'(t) = \left( \cos(t), t\cos(t^2), ~\ldots~,~ t^{n-1}\cos(t^n)~,~ \ldots\right).$$

**And this can fail to be in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$**, at least for $t > 1$. But $\alpha$ had no problems at $t > 1$!

I guess one of two things is happening here:

$1$) This curve $\alpha$ is not really smooth in $l^2$; or

$2$) Its derivative is not what you get by computing the derivative entrywise.

Either one of these things seems surprising to me. So, what is going on?

Comment: 1) $\alpha$ is not a smooth curve. It is merely componentwise smooth, that is a much weaker property.

Comment: I would ask yourself, "what does smooth mean here?"

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. Still, I had in mind a statement like, "$\alpha$ is smooth if and only if $f \circ \alpha$ is smooth for every linear functional $f$". Then if you check this for each functional of the form $dx^i$, it seems to hold..

Comment: But the coordinate functionals are just a small subset of all continuous linear functionals. Consider $\xi = (1,1/2,1/3,\dotsc)$, then $$\langle \xi, \alpha(t)\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (t^n)}{n^2},$$ which is _not_ smooth.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah! I made the mistake of thinking, "checking this for a basis is enough". Very nice counterexample, thank you!

Comment: It would be enough to check it for a Hamel basis.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. But those would have to be uncountable and nasty. :) If you copy/paste your comment into an answer I'll accept it so this doesn't remain 'unanswered'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve $\alpha$ is not smooth, it is only componentwise smooth, which is a weaker property.

If a curve $\beta \colon \mathbb{R}\to l^2(\mathbb{N})$ is smooth, you get the derivative by componentwise differentiation, so if componentwise differentiation yields something not belonging to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, that proves that the curve is not smooth.